# Repeating Local Notifications from Start Date to End Date and also 1-4 times in a day Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, uilocalnotification, android-pendingintent

I'm having an app in which I need to set some local notifications with the data I have. I am able to get the local notifications for the hard coded time value using AlarmManager, PendingIntent and BroadcastReciever.

Now my question is I need to set up the local notifications/reminders from a start date to end date and it can be 1-4 times per day(i.e Frequenecy can be 1-4 with 4 different times).

Say

```
Start Date : June 3 2019

END Date   : June 30 2019

Frequency  : 2 times a day at 9:00 AM(Time1) and 6.00PM(Time2)
```

Starting from June 3rd I should get Local Notifications every day at 9.00 AM and 6.00 PM till June 30th.

**Updated Issue** Last pending Notification is getting showed every time when I run the app i.e if I have one notification scheduled for 5.30 PM today and if I run the app at 6.00 PM my app is showing the 5.30 PM notification.Similarly if I have my last notification scheduled yesterday at some 7.00 PM say, it is getting showed today when I run the app. How to cancel or clear that notification.

***Main Activity method**

```
scheduleNotificationsMethod() {

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mCtx.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        if(treatment.getSCHEDULE().equalsIgnoreCase("Daily")) {
            String[] times = {treatment.getTIME1(), treatment.getTIME2(), treatment.getTIME3(), treatment.getTIME4()};
            for(String time : times) {
                if(time != null && time != "") {

                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTime(fromISO8601UTC(time));
                    int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    date1 = createDate(hours, minutes);
                    time1 = date1.getTime();

                    intent.putExtra(MEDICINE_TIME, toISO8601UTC(fromISO8601UTC(time)));
                    intent.putExtra(END_DATE, treatment.getEndDate());

                    String reqCode1 = treatment.getID()+""+treatment.getMedicineName()+""+hours+""+minutes;
                    int req1 = reqCode1.hashCode();
                    intent.putExtra(REQUEST_CODE, req1);

                    pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mCtx, req1, intent, 0);
                    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time1, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent1);

                }
            }
        }
}
```

**Notification Receiver Class**

```
public class NotificationReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

private final String CHANNEL_ID = "personal_notifications";
public static String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "notificationMessage";
private Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("Utils Inside NotificationReciever onReceive");
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
    this.context = context;
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("SHOW_ALERT_CARD"));

    String action = "It's time to take your medicine!";
    String endDate = intent.getStringExtra("END_DATE");
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("MEDICINE_TIME");
    int requestCode = intent.getIntExtra("REQUEST_CODE", 0);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, resultIntent, 0);
    buildNotification(context, pendingIntent, msg);

public void buildNotification(Context context, PendingIntent pendingIntent, String msg) {
    System.out.println("Utils Inside callTheMethod");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    int color = 0xffffaa00;

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_dosage_c);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setContentTitle("It's time to take your medicine!");
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentText(msg);
    builder.setSound(soundUri);
    builder.setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000);
    builder.setColor(color);

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(102938, notification);
}
}
```

Comment: What happens? What is exactly your question?

Comment: I am able to get local notification one time i.e at 3:45 PM(from below code) by making use of calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);. How can I set such similar Local Notifications from a start date to end date with a frequency of 1-4 times a day.

Comment: @DavidWasser Can you look at my updated code once and let me know where I'm doing wrong.And how to set reminders for particular days of a week.

Comment: Please remove `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`, this often causes problems and is not needed.

Comment: Also, please tell me what happens and what is not working. I can't guess from this code what it is doing or not doing.

Comment: I should replace with PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT with? The problem is the alarm scheduled for 3.15 PM is showing up at around 5 PM i.e Reminders are getting triggered at wrong time .

Comment: Also, I can have like 2 to 3 diff medicines(say) in a day with diff frequencies(1-4 times). So for that do I need to implement anything separately or will the above code work?

Comment: Replace `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` with `0`.

Comment: You are using `setInexactRepeating()`. Inexact means just that. It means that Android can delay the alarm. If you want the alarm to appear exactly at that time, then use one of the exact forms. In general, it is better to use non-repeating alarms and just schedule the next one when the current one goes off.

Comment: @DavidWasser I replaced PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT with 0 and changed setInexactRepeating() to setRepeating(). But still no luck(means the reminders are not getting trigged at correct time).I tried making use of diff PendingIntents.It would be helpful if you can go through my code once.

Comment: Your code looks OK. Repeating alarms are notoriously inaccurate. Please read https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms and understand that if the device is sleeping or dozing then alarms will not trigger. If it is important that your alarms trigger at the correct time, you need to use another approach (several suggestions are mentioned in the linked article)

Comment: Also be aware that manufacturers have different implementations of the `AlarmManager` behaviour. Some are more restrictive as a "power-saving" feature.

Comment: @DavidWasser  thanks for answering to all my queries. One last question, can you explain what happens in the below three scenarios 1)Same PendingIntent with diff ACTION 2) Diff pending Intents with Same Request Code 3)Diff Pending Intents with Diff Request Code

Comment: What do you mean by **same `PendingIntent`** and **different `PendingIntent`**?

Comment: When you set an alarm, the `AlarmManager` cancels any previously set alarm that **matches the `PendingIntent` that you provide**. This is why, when you want to set multiple alarms in parallel, that you need to ensure that the `PendingIntent`s are "unique".

Comment: @DavidWasser Can you once have a look at my Updated Issue in the question?

Comment: When you run the app you need to check the the alarm time has already passed. If so, you don't set the alarm.

Comment: Also, if my answer was helpful for you, you should accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set as many alarms as you like. The trick here is to make sure that they are considered "unique" by the `AlarmManager`. To make them "unique" you can use one of the following methods:

- Use a different (unique) `requestCode` parameter in the call to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`
- Use a different (unique) ACTION or DATA in the `Intent` you pass to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`

There is no way to set an alarm to repeat on a daily basis for a certain number of days. However, you can set an alarm to repeat every day and when the alarm triggers, check in your `BroadcastReceiver` if the alarm has triggered for the last time, and if so, cancel it so that it doesn't trigger any more in the future. To do this, you will need to remember the day that it "expires", which you can do by either storing that information in a database or `SharedPreferences`, or by adding this information as an "extra" to the `Intent` which is passed to the `BroadcastReceiver`.

**NOTE:** Android has many rules about scheduling alarms to try to optimize battery life. If your alarm doesn't need to trigger at an exact time, Android will modify the schedule to a more optimal time. There are ways to get the alarm to trigger at an exact time, but you cannot reliably set a repeating exact time alarm. If you need exact time, schedule the alarm once and when it triggers, schedule the next one. Read about the way `AlarmManager` works and how to best schedule your alarms on https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

Comment: Hey David. Thanks for the answer. I was busy with some other work and didn't look much into this. I will try out the way you told and get back to you if I'm stuck anywhere

Comment: Hey David, Can you look at my updated code and let me know where I'm doing wrong. I have set up different actions as you suggested but it's not working.